# Type is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-props, children

I have this component

```
import React, { FunctionComponent, useEffect } from 'react';
import shouldForwardProp from '@styled-system/should-forward-prop';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const delay = 0.25;

interface FadeInSectionProps {
  offset?: number;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const Section = styled.div.withConfig({
  shouldForwardProp,
})<{ offset?: number }>`
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out opacity, 0.5s ease-in-out transform;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(0, -40px);

  &.fade-in-section--is-visible {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }

  transition-delay: ${(props) => (props.offset ? props.offset * delay + 's' : '0s')};
`;

export const FadeInSection: FunctionComponent = ({ offset, children }: FadeInSectionProps) => {
  const [isVisible, setVisible] = React.useState(false);
  const domRef = React.useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
      entries.forEach((entry) => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          setVisible(true);
        }
      });
    });

    observer.observe(domRef.current);
  }, []);
  return (
    <Section
      className={`fade-in-section ${isVisible ? 'fade-in-section--is-visible' : ''}`}
      ref={domRef}
      offset={offset}
    >
      {children}
    </Section>
  );
};

export default FadeInSection;
```

Which I'm using (after importing it) like so:

```
<FadeInSection>
   <Header />
<FadeInSection>
```

or

```
<div>
   <FadeInSection>
     <Item1 />
   </FadeInSection>
   <FadeInSection offset={1}>
     <Item1 />
   </FadeInSection>
</div>
```

But when I pass the prop offset I get this ts error (even that works as I expected)
[image]

En english:

```
    Type '{ type: string; name: string; value: string; onChange: (e: any) => void; placeholder: string; label: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InputProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'type' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InputProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.ts(2322)
```

What I'm doing wrong? Or how Can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this the warning in the ide was gone and also the errors in the lint command

```
export const FadeInSection: FunctionComponent<FadeInSectionProps> = ({
  offset,
  children,
}: FadeInSectionProps) => {
   return (<Section />);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try changing `const FadeInSection: FunctionComponent = ({ offset, children }: FadeInSectionProps)` to `const FadeInSection: FunctionComponent<FadeInSectionProps> = ({ offset, children })`

You type the component with `FunctionComponent` instead of props, so you can use internal props like `children`, without the need to type them. (you can actually remove children from your interface, cause it exists on FunctionComponent interface). What is happening is that you specify the type of const FadeInSection not the type of props, so when you used it previously, compiler didn't look into your interface at all

Comment: The error is gone, could you try to explain why? thanks!

Comment: It is done internally by React I suppose, so you can use internal props like `children`, without the need to type them. (you can actually remove `children` from your interface, cause it exists on `FunctionComponent` interface). What is happening is that you specify the type of `const FadeInSection` not the type of `props`, so when you used it previously, compiler didn't look into your interface at all

Comment: I see, could you move this info to you answer so I can accept it? ;)

Comment: Sorry but now 2 lint errors appeared with your code when I run the lint comand: `27:72  error  'offset' is missing in props validation    react/prop-types` and 
 `27:80  error  'children' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types` any idea why?

Comment: Thats probably eslint-parser error since you typed the variable, but not the props, and parser cant pass props validation, try typing your props as well, should solve the problem, or updating/configuring the parser. Here is similar issue on github
https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/3075

Comment: This kind of problems is why Typescript is hard to use. You end up spending couple of hours just to pass a props. OMG